# RecyclerView Item missing on keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

Below is a horizontal recycler view of colors.  So I'm having this weird issue where when the keyboard pops open the first half of the recycler view items aren't visible. As you can see on view inspection the views are still there just not visible. Not sure what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

> ScreenShots

#### At the start of Fragment

[image: At the start of Fragment]

#### When keyboard shows up

[image: When keyboard shows up]

Edit: 
For people down voting please leave a reason.

### CODE

#### Holder

```
public class StylizedColorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StylizedColorViewHolder> {
    private List<String> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Subject<String> colorChangePublisher;
    private static final int DEFAULT_COLOR_POSITION = 7;

    public StylizedColorAdapter(Context context, Subject<String> colorChangePublisher) {
        this.colorChangePublisher = colorChangePublisher;
        String[] allColors = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.selectable_colors);
        colorList.addAll(Arrays.asList(allColors));
    }

    @Override public StylizedColorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_color_selector, parent, false);
        return new StylizedColorViewHolder(row, colorChangePublisher);
    }

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(StylizedColorViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setColor(colorList.get(position));
    }

    @Override public int getItemCount() {
        return colorList.size();
    }

    public String getStartingColor() {
        return colorList.get(DEFAULT_COLOR_POSITION);
    }
}
```

#### Holder

```
public class StylizedColorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.color_selector) CircleImageView ivColorSelector;
    @BindView(R.id.color_selector_selected) ImageView ivColorSelected;
    private View row;
    private Subject<String> colorChangePublisher;

    public StylizedColorViewHolder(View row, Subject<String> colorChangePublisher) {
        super(row);
        this.row = row;
        this.colorChangePublisher = colorChangePublisher;
        ButterKnife.bind(this, row);
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        ivColorSelector.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(color));
        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("#FFFFFF")) {
            ivColorSelector.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(row.getContext(), R.color.colorLighterGrey));
        } else {
            ivColorSelector.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(row.getContext(), R.color.colorWhite));
        }
        ivColorSelector.setOnClickListener(v -> colorChangePublisher.onNext(color));
    }
}
```

#### Use of adapter

```
RecyclerView stylizedColorList = stylizedLayout.findViewById(R.id.stylized_text_color);
colorAdapter = new StylizedColorAdapter(getContext(), colorChangePublisher);
stylizedColorList.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
```

Comment: Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity in the manifest.

Comment: do you use a custom keyboard,try switching back to the default one see if the error repeats itself

Comment: @Jantzilla I already have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` set.

Comment: @InnerFire This screenshot is from the emulator and that using the default keyboard.

Comment: .post your code